# check if date has exceeded 1year in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite, t-sql

```
ID  Source  Date           Desc      flgdeladvsourcedetails
22  5       1-Oct-12       a              NULL
23  5       1-Nov-12       b              NULL
24  5       1-Dec-12       c              NULL
25  5       1-Nov-12       d              NULL
26  5       1-Dec-12       e              NULL
27  5       1-Sep-12       f              NULL
28  5       24-Sep-12      g              NULL
29  5       7-Aug-12       h              NULL
30  5       1-Sep-12       i              NULL
31  5       1-Sep-12       j              NULL
32  5       15-Sep-12      k              NULL
```

Above dates are contract start dates. I have to display records whose contract date does not exceed 1 year.

After 1 year of this date the record should not be displayed.

i want to check individual dates of table. not with current date.like example. 1 oct 12 data will not be seen if current date is 2nd oct 2013

Answer (score 7):

Use `DATEADD()` to compare the `[Date]` with the date 1 year ago:

```
SELECT ID, Source, Date, Desc, flgdeladvsourcedetails
FROM table
WHERE DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())<[Date]
```

Comment: i want to check individual dates of table. not with current date.like example. 1oct12 data will not be seen after 2nd oct 2013

Comment: When you say 2nd Oct 2013, are you referring to when the **current date** is 2nd Oct 2013?

Comment: Thanks, I am working on a project to show previous and upcoming events, which did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WHERE` and [`DATEADD`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
SELECT ID, SOURCE, DATE, DESC
FROM YourTable
WHERE DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) < [DATE]
```

Comment: This will show all dates less than 1 year into the future...?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select id, source, date, desc, flg...
from table where dateadd(year,1,[date]) > getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful

```
select * from TableName where CAST(DateAdd(YEAR,1, Date)AS date) < CAST(getdate() AS DATE)
```